# Unable to SSH into computer unless logged in locally

Tags: macos, ssh

I've set up Remote Login on a Mac Mini running 10.8.4. After configuring port forwarding on my router, I'm able to SSH into this computer, whether from an external or internal computer.

From what I've read, it seems like the SSH server is set up to run at boot. But the problem is that if no one is logged in locally, I cannot SSH into the computer. The connection simply times out. Although I've authorized SSH access (via password) to only one of the administrators, it doesn't seem to matter who is logged in.

Does anyone know how to allow SSH access without needing a local user to be logged in?

Thanks!

Comment: Running ssh as a service might help

Comment: Have you done any modifications to SSH-config files, or did you the setup completely from within Sharing-preferences?

Comment: Scandalist, I thought by default SSH runs as a service when started. Pasi, I just activated Remote Login from the Preferences pane.